# i want to extract href for the links in this particular website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can you please help me figure this out?
i'm trying to scrape this website https://industrydirectory.mjbizdaily.com/accounting/
i'm trying to scrape all the links such as
https://industrydirectory.mjbizdaily.com/420-businesses/
but i can't figure it out

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://industrydirectory.mjbizdaily.com/accounting/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
test = soup.find_all('ul', class_='business-results')
print(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#main a` to get all urls:

```
urls = [url["href"] for url in soup.select("#main a")]
```

List of dictionaries with key as a text and value as a URL:

```
urls = []
for url in soup.select("#main a"):
    print(url.text, url["href"])
    urls.append({url.text: url["href"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
for each in test:
  li = each.findAll('li')
  for a in li:
    print(a.find('a').attrs['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this but i tried this in another way the problem is when you go to the website and inspect it you will find that each section has its own ul i want all the url